# How to hide image when dynamically change src attribute in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Is there a way to hide or remove image while loading a new one, when changing src tag value.

Example code:

```
<img [src]="dynamicPath">
<button (click)="changeSrc()">Change Image Src</button>
```

In component:

```
dynamicPath = 'somePath.jpg';
changeSrc(){
    this.dynamicPath = 'newPath.jpg';
}
```

The problem with this code is that after clicking the button, old image is still showing until new image has completely loaded, which is undesired.
Is there a way to remove it or show a hint that new image is being loaded?

Note that: my case doesn't allow solution of preloading many images at once.

Comment: Use ngClass on the image element. Within your `changeSrc()` method change the property that would add a class that might include a "spinner" opaquely over the existing image. Use an onload handler for the image to remove the spinner class dynamically via ngClass

Comment: @RandyCasburn, thank you... So obvious yet It didn't cross my mind... I'm using onload event to hide spinner after initial loading, but somehow I forgot that I can reset that property when pressing the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the image from the DOM using `*ngIf` as below,

```
<img *ngIf="dynamicPath!=''" [src]="dynamicPath">
<button (click)="changeSrc()">Change Image Src</button>
```

you can set the variable to empty string `' '` as below

```
dynamicPath = 'somePath.jpg';
changeSrc(){
      this.dynamicPath ='';
      this.dynamicPath = 'newPath.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just hookup the load event of the image.

html

```
<img [src]="dynamicPath" (load)="onload()" *ngIf="loadingImg">
<button (click)="changeSrc()">Change Image Src</button>
```

ts

```
loadingImg = true;
dynamicPath = 'somePath.jpg';
changeSrc(){
    this.loadingImg = true;
    this.dynamicPath = 'newPath.jpg';
}

  onload() {
    this.loadingImg = false;
  }
```

Comment: This is a great solution because it also allows you to add a fade out and in effect via CSS by adding a class as soon as the image is changed and removing this class again when the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *ngIf in the img tag.

```
<img *ngIf="!loading" [src]="Path">
<button (click)="changeSrc()">Change Image Src</button>
```

Then you can make decision in the component.

```
Path = 'somePath.jpg';
loading=false;
changeSrc(){
  this.loading =true;
  this.Path = 'newPath.jpg';
  this.loading =false;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, this won't solve the issue with the time the browser has to actually load the image.